# detect offline or online using service worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, offline

I am using service worker to check if a user is online or offline when a request is made. Here are some of the approaches I have taken:

1. In this method in service worker,

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
    if (navigator.onLine){

    }
})
```

`navigator.onLine` only works when you check/uncheck the offline checkbox in Inspect Element. But when I switch the device's internet on/off, it will always return true whether im offline or online.
And also from what i've seen in other answers,  `navigator.onLine` will return true if you are connected to your local network even if your local network has no internet connection.

2. I have tried to ping a url in the `self.addEventListener("fetch", {...})` method as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378589/6756827. This will bring an error in in the `new XMLHttpRequest();` object.
3. I have tried to load an online resource (an image) in the `self.addEventListener("fetch", {...})` method as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29823818/6756827. The console shows an error for `new Image();`.

Because none of these approaches work, how do we check if a user is online or offline in service worker when a request is made ?

Comment: As a general rule, the only way to know at some given moment if an internet connection has been made is to attempt to make contact to some other host and get a response. That's pretty much how the Internet works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the service worker you do not have access to the navigator object and thus no access to the online property or events.

Instead you know you are offline when a fetch throws an exception. The only time a fetch will throw an exception is when the device cannot connect to the Internet/Network.

```
self.addEventListener( "fetch", function ( event ) {

event.respondWith(

    handleRequest( event )
    .catch( err => {
        //assume offline as everything else should be handled
        return caches.match( doc_fallback, {
            ignoreSearch: true
        } );

    } )

);
```

} );

For a more complex handling of the situation you can sync messages of online/offline state with the UI using the message API:

```
self.addEventListener( "message", event => {
    //handle message here
}
```